# No route matches for new show route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
ActionController::RoutingError

No route matches {:controller=>"user_prices", :action=>"show".....
```

This is the error I am getting when I changed my route in my view to:

```
<td class="show-link"><%= link_to "Show", show_price_path(user_price) %></td>
```

Which is from my new route:

```
match "/:id/:product_name/:purchase_date/:price", :to => "user_prices#show", :as => :show_price
```

What do I have to do so I can use this route to see my user prices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The route that you are specifying

```
/:id/:product_name/:purchase_date/:price
```

requires 4 parameters for it to be created.  You are only passing in one object, which I assume is meant to be for the id.  With the route that you have specified, you will need to do something like.

```
show_price_path(:id=>user_price.id, :product_name=>product_name_from_user_price, :purchase_date=>purchase_date_from_user_price, :price=>price_from_user_price)
```